# Unity 2021.3.10f1 iOS build crashes when startup EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, sigabrt

I built the game in Unity 2021.3.10f1 iOS to Xcode.

Then in MacOS Ventura opened the build folder in the terminal.

Terminated:

- pod install

  arch -x86_64 pod install

  chmod +x process_symbols.sh

Then opened the file `Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace` in Xcode 14.2 (14C18).

- In PROJECT->Unity-iPhone->Build Settings->Build Options->Enable
  Bitcode set to No

  In TARGET->Unity-iPhone->Build Settings->Build Options->Always Embed
  Swift Standard Libraries set to Yes

  In TARGET->Unity-UnityFramework->Build Settings->Build
  Options->Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries set to No

Then archive the project with Product-> Archive and test it with iOS TestFlight.

Got a Crash on startup, in `crashlog.crash` was a description of the crash, but don't get it how to solve it.

```
Incident Identifier: CE6A928D-38E3-4E2C-83E5-A27D9BCE8079
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,8
Process:             Surviwar.io [17655]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF0A9681-11F1-4BC0-852C-3060DFB00EDA/Surviwar.io.app/Surviwar.io
Identifier:          com.WindCompany.Surviwar.io
Version:             0.9.8 (0)
AppStoreTools:       14C17
AppVariant:          1:iPhone11,8:16
Beta:                YES
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.WindCompany.Surviwar.io [1345]

Date/Time:           2022-12-18 22:35:04.6693 +0400
Launch Time:         2022-12-18 22:35:03.5417 +0400
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.1.1 (20B101)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    5.01.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  5

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1ce6fde88 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1c7a378d8 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1ce86a794 -[NSException raise] + 16 (NSException.m:113)
3   UnityFramework                  0x107cddae8 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly + 348
4   UnityFramework                  0x107cddca4 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly + 792
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d5ccc4b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d5ccdfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d5cd10c8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 788 (inline_internal.h:2632)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d5cdfa6c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396 (inline_internal.h:0)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x1d5ce0284 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:7052)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21b753dbc _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2631)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x21b753b98 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0:
0   dyld                            0x00000001ecdc8578 objc::ObjectHashTable::forEachObject(char const*, void (unsigned long long, unsigned short, bool&) block_pointer) const + 76 (OptimizerObjC.h:295)
1   dyld                            0x00000001ecdc8554 objc::ObjectHashTable::forEachObject(char const*, void (unsigned long long, unsigned short, bool&) block_pointer) const + 40 (OptimizerObjC.h:404)
2   dyld                            0x00000001ecdc8504 dyld4::APIs::_dyld_for_each_objc_class(char const*, void (void*, bool, bool*) block_pointer) + 168 (OptimizerObjC.h:576)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a29ac8 getClass_impl(char const*) + 176 (objc-opt.mm:404)
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a26e5c getClassExceptSomeSwift(char const*) + 24 (objc-runtime-new.mm:1790)
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a2577c look_up_class + 92 (objc-runtime-new.mm:7838)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001c8b09c50 NSClassFromString + 156 (NSObjCRuntime.m:0)
7   UnityFramework                  0x00000001083d5e70 InitMetalSupport() + 260 (MetalSupport.mm:53)
8   UnityFramework                  0x00000001083b31c0 CreateMetalGfxDevice() + 16 (GfxDeviceMetal.mm:2184)
9   UnityFramework                  0x0000000107fbccd0 CreateClientGfxDevice(GfxDeviceRenderer, GfxCreateDeviceFlags) + 184 (GfxDeviceClient.cpp:116)
10  UnityFramework                  0x000000010827e9fc CreateGfxDevice(GfxDeviceRenderer, GfxCreateDeviceFlags) + 264 (GfxDeviceSetup.cpp:602)
11  UnityFramework                  0x000000010827ea94 InitializeGfxDevice() + 112 (GfxDeviceSetup.cpp:784)
12  UnityFramework                  0x000000010839e4f4 UnityInitApplicationGraphics + 20 (LibEntryPoint.mm:189)
13  UnityFramework                  0x00000001079f2308 -[UnityAppController startUnity:] + 52 (UnityAppController.mm:121)
14  Foundation                      0x00000001c8b4f898 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 372 (NSRunLoop.m:646)
15  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce7c235c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32 (CFRunLoop.c:1797)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce77e9d8 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 940 (CFRunLoop.c:2402)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce722598 __CFRunLoopDoTimers + 288 (CFRunLoop.c:2560)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce76ffcc __CFRunLoopRun + 1896 (CFRunLoop.c:3120)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce774ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3418)
20  GraphicsServices                0x0000000207a72368 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
21  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d0c533d0 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3745)
22  UIKitCore                       0x00000001d0c53034 UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5335)
23  UnityFramework                  0x00000001079f6e98 -[UnityFramework runUIApplicationMainWithArgc:argv:] + 92 (main.mm:96)
24  Surviwar.io                     0x0000000104fbbccc main + 60 (main.mm:26)
25  dyld                            0x00000001ecddc960 start + 2528 (dyldMain.cpp:1170)

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753b90 start_wqthread + 0 (:-1)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020b2f2680 __ulock_wait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000021b6be82c _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 172 (lock.c:578)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a279b4 lookUpImpOrForward + 156 (lock_private.h:716)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a220c4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68 (:-1)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce72ea3c -[CFPrefsPlistSource handleReply:toRequestNewDataMessage:onConnection:retryCount:error:] + 2760 (CFPrefsPlistSource.m:1636)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce72ddc0 -[CFPrefsPlistSource sendRequestNewDataMessage:toConnection:retryCount:error:] + 640 (CFPrefsPlistSource.m:1697)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce712a38 __50-[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_requestNewData]_block_invoke + 200 (CFPrefsPlistSource.m:1324)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce894540 -[_CFXPreferences withConnectionForRole:andUserIdentifier:performBlock:] + 52 (CFXPreferences.m:1690)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce7c09d0 -[CFPrefsPlistSource alreadylocked_requestNewData] + 424 (CFPrefsPlistSource.m:1320)
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce7412e8 _copyValueForKey + 268 (CFPrefsPlistSource.m:227)
10  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce73a5c8 -[CFPrefsPlistSource copyValueForKey:] + 60 (CFPrefsPlistSource.m:298)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce73a574 __66-[_CFXPreferences copyValueForKey:identifier:user:host:container:]_block_invoke + 32 (CFXPreferences.m:1064)
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce76ba78 -[_CFXPreferences withSourceForIdentifier:user:byHost:container:cloud:perform:] + 828 (CFPrefsSource.m:1183)
13  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce71faac -[_CFXPreferences copyValueForKey:identifier:user:host:container:] + 212 (CFXPreferences.m:1058)
14  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce71f9a0 _CFPreferencesCopyValueWithContainer + 120 (CFXPreferences.m:2320)
15  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d68598 -[HTPrefs prefNamed:domain:profile:matchingSelector:contextPrefixOut:] + 368 (HTPrefs.m:161)
16  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d68784 -[HTPrefs boolProperty:contextPrefixOut:] + 84 (HTPrefs.m:218)
17  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d6412c -[HTPrefs initBoolProperty:] + 68 (HTPrefs.m:341)
18  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d64694 -[HTPrefs earlyInitNecessaryPrefs] + 144 (HTPrefs.m:1150)
19  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d63c04 -[HTPrefs setupPrefsWithQueue:profilePath:taskingDomainName:hangtracerDomain:setupInternalPrefs:] + 172 (HTPrefs.m:1223)
20  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d63b30 -[HTPrefs setupPrefsWithQueue:] + 88 (HTPrefs.m:1203)
21  HangTracer                      0x00000001f3d6a55c __HTHangEventCreateWithBundleID_block_invoke.26 + 52 (HangTracer.m:431)
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccc4b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccdfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd5694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672 (inline_internal.h:2632)
25  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd61e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384 (queue.c:3940)
26  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ce0e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652 (queue.c:6846)
27  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2618)
28  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753b98 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020b2f5a5c __unlink + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020b2f9a34 unlink + 16 (unlink.c:30)
2   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f24a34c8 unixDelete + 64 (sqlite3.c:47222)
3   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f2485a78 pager_end_transaction + 840 (sqlite3.c:25661)
4   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f2485454 sqlite3BtreeCommitPhaseTwo + 184 (sqlite3.c:67998)
5   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f24503c0 sqlite3VdbeHalt + 2776 (sqlite3.c:90619)
6   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f247eedc sqlite3VdbeExec + 55972 (sqlite3.c:97084)
7   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f2470914 sqlite3_step + 1296 (sqlite3.c:94068)
8   libsqlite3.dylib                0x00000001f2435928 sqlite3_exec + 368 (sqlite3.c:137052)
9   UnityFramework                  0x0000000107d015b4 GADInitializerSettings + 1264
10  UnityFramework                  0x0000000107d012a8 GADInitializerSettings + 484
11  UnityFramework                  0x0000000107d01198 GADInitializerSettings + 212
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccdfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccf828 _dispatch_once_callout + 32 (once.c:52)
14  UnityFramework                  0x0000000107d01174 GADInitializerSettings + 176
15  UnityFramework                  0x0000000107cde770 GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly + 3556
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccc4b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccdfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd10c8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 788 (inline_internal.h:2632)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cdfa6c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396 (inline_internal.h:0)
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ce0284 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:7052)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753dbc _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2631)
22  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753b98 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020b2f2680 __ulock_wait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000021b6be82c _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 172 (lock.c:578)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a279b4 lookUpImpOrForward + 156 (lock_private.h:716)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a220c4 _objc_msgSend_uncached + 68 (:-1)
4   UnityFramework                  0x0000000107be08bc -[APMUserDefaults integerForKey:] + 56
5   UnityFramework                  0x0000000107b9562c -[APMMonitor migrateMonitorDataOnMonitorQueue] + 64
6   UnityFramework                  0x0000000107b93504 __53-[APMMonitor initWithLogLevel:logger:libraryVersion:]_block_invoke + 44
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccc4b4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1518)
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccdfdc _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:560)
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd5694 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 672 (inline_internal.h:2632)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd61e0 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 384 (queue.c:3940)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ce0e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652 (queue.c:6846)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2618)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753b98 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020b2f8200 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b75a1ac pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001d5d31c8c abort + 180 (abort.c:118)
3   UnityFramework                  0x00000001086eb01c uncaught_exception_handler.cold.1 + 28 (PLCrashReporter.m:369)
4   UnityFramework                  0x000000010863d5b0 uncaught_exception_handler + 44 (PLCrashReporter.m:366)
5   UnityFramework                  0x00000001079fb018 UncaughtExceptionHandler(NSException*) + 148 (CrashReporter.mm:89)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001ce809060 __handleUncaughtException + 636 (NSException.m:273)
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a3dd30 _objc_terminate() + 132 (objc-exception.mm:497)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000021b699f28 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000021b699ec4 std::terminate() + 56 (cxa_handlers.cpp:88)
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ccdff0 _dispatch_client_callout + 40 (object.m:563)
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd10c8 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 788 (inline_internal.h:2632)
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cdfa6c _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396 (inline_internal.h:0)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ce0284 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164 (queue.c:7052)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753dbc _pthread_wqthread + 228 (pthread.c:2631)
15  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753b98 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6 name:
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020b2f2680 __ulock_wait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x000000021b6be82c _os_unfair_lock_lock_slow + 172 (lock.c:578)
2   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a25404 class_conformsToProtocol + 104 (lock_private.h:716)
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c7a2ec08 +[NSObject conformsToProtocol:] + 48 (NSObject.mm:2451)
4   Foundation                      0x00000001c8b00f60 -[NSXPCDecoder _validateAllowedClass:forKey:allowingInvocations:] + 276 (NSXPCCoder.m:760)
5   Foundation                      0x00000001c9130cac _decodeObject + 812 (NSXPCCoder.m:942)
6   Foundation                      0x00000001c8b45660 -[NSXPCDecoder _decodeObjectOfClasses:atObject:] + 76 (NSXPCCoder.m:1120)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001c8b45134 _NSXPCSerializationDecodeTypedObjCValuesFromArray + 892 (NSXPCCoder_InvocationSerialization.m:402)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001c8b8cf70 _NSXPCSerializationDecodeInvocationArgumentArray + 412 (NSXPCCoder_InvocationSerialization.m:537)
9   Foundation                      0x00000001c913167c -[NSXPCDecoder __decodeXPCObject:allowingSimpleMessageSend:outInvocation:outArguments:outArgumentsMaxCount:outMethodSignature:outSelector:isReply:replySelector:] + 700 (NSXPCCoder.m:1258)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001c9131394 -[NSXPCDecoder _decodeReplyFromXPCObject:forSelector:] + 76 (NSXPCCoder.m:1152)
11  Foundation                      0x00000001c8b52de4 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 252 (NSXPCConnection.m:259)
12  Foundation                      0x00000001c912c2e4 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_5 + 188 (NSXPCConnection.m:1662)
13  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000021b7b4f1c _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 124 (serializer.c:119)
14  libxpc.dylib                    0x000000021b7a7fb4 _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 88 (connection.c:857)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cce05c _dispatch_client_callout3 + 20 (object.m:586)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cebf58 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 344 (mach.c:2462)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd556c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376 (inline_internal.h:0)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5cd6214 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 436 (queue.c:3940)
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001d5ce0e10 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 652 (queue.c:6846)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753df8 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2618)
21  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021b753b98 start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

<There was 30+ threads, but i removed them because of character limit on message>

Thread 5 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000010   x5: 0x0000000000000060   x6: 0x00000002804c8060   x7: 0xffffffff00002500
    x8: 0x83d46d0ca407f6b2   x9: 0x83d46d0dcf0086b2  x10: 0x00000002cfdc3bb8  x11: 0x003f0001210eb800
   x12: 0x000000000000003f  x13: 0x00000001210ebbe0  x14: 0x0400000224d748f9  x15: 0x0000000224d748f8
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000016b077000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000002a07  x21: 0x000000016b0770e0  x22: 0x0000000282fc8510  x23: 0x0000000226160580
   x24: 0x000000000000000c  x25: 0x00000001cea38a4e  x26: 0x00000002256c08d0  x27: 0x0000000223a8a000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016b076c90   lr: 0x000000021b75a1ac
    sp: 0x000000016b076c70   pc: 0x000000020b2f8200 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x104fb4000 - 0x104fbbfff Surviwar.io arm64  <4e955d7aa21f350dbe73241ec5796fcb> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF0A9681-11F1-4BC0-852C-3060DFB00EDA/Surviwar.io.app/Surviwar.io
0x1079e0000 - 0x109d37fff UnityFramework arm64  <c56d5addbcd73e0d8dac0bed2cca2981> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EF0A9681-11F1-4BC0-852C-3060DFB00EDA/Surviwar.io.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
0x1c7a20000 - 0x1c7a63e1f libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <ab79707faf643ba588993b711c6cff5c> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1c8ae0000 - 0x1c9429fff Foundation arm64e  <c431acb6fe043d28b6774de6e1c7d81f> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1ce6f4000 - 0x1cead9fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <5cdc5d9ae5063740b64ebb30867b4f1b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1d08b1000 - 0x1d208efff UIKitCore arm64e  <179501b60fc2344ab969b4e3961ebe10> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1d5cca000 - 0x1d5d10fff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <fea36690a0003c55b7009120b05aa69b> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1d5d11000 - 0x1d5d90ff7 libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <dad0ce088f353ff4899e43dc44eb65a7> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1ecdc7000 - 0x1ece4a00f dyld arm64e  <cb3ff411476234d286a4eca13f9fb6c3> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1f242c000 - 0x1f25cbffb libsqlite3.dylib arm64e  <9e91ccf4fee23cc5882f22663791d295> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1f3d62000 - 0x1f3d75fff HangTracer arm64e  <ed827138febb3b109922975f908300da> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/HangTracer.framework/HangTracer
0x207a71000 - 0x207a79fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <a633a095122639428f413877660185ee> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x20b2f1000 - 0x20b327ffb libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <ff27fc8f90ba3332ab7ac5bc2d9ca7b1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x21b689000 - 0x21b6a0ffb libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <fa871417be083e90b33ca6aa89813f3b> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x21b6be000 - 0x21b6c4ff3 libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <29a26364acef38c28b0ddb0dfca0bb65> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x21b753000 - 0x21b75efff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <1aa3a4b6f9e730568c8b4e4dd81312a4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x21b797000 - 0x21b7d7fff libxpc.dylib arm64e  <7a0ca8d2728537ddae972efaa1de763e> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

EOF
```

I tried to get more information with debug build but crashlog was same.